# Getting 429 error when working with Parse Server (Cloud Code)

Tags: parse-platform, twilio, parse-server, twilio-api, authy

I am trying to work with Authy verification; however, I am not able to work with it.
I am currently using Parse Server with CloudCode to work with it, here is a snapshot of the code :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("SendSMS", async (request) => {
  client.verify.services.create({
      friendlyName: 'verificationService'
    })
    .then(service => {
      console.log('service 1 ', service);
    }, err => {
      console.error('err ', err);
    });
});
```

The problem is that Twilio's API throws :

```
{ [Error: Too many requests]
  status: 429,
  message: 'Too many requests',
  code: 20429,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20429',
  detail: undefined }
```

By the way, when trying to send SMS it works without any issues "using client.sendSms()" the issue is only related with "client.verify.services.create()"

Comment: Have you looked at the [url](https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20429) within the error message? It seems that you are calling this function and therefore calling Twilio's api too many times.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo already looked at that, but as you can see from the cloud function, it's called only once. I am trying to apply the following: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification not sure if it's the right way to implement it using Cloud code or the code should be written differently.

Comment: You can do it through cloud code and the way you are writing the cloud code seems right. But I see that the way you are using the Twilio api is different in comparison to the link you sent. Why don't you try just like the example in the link?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo thanks for debugging with me, it turns that the error came from Twilio, after contacting them everything worked fine.

Comment: Nice! I'm glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to put an await clause before the first function.

```
 await client.verify.services.create({
```